# Breakpoint is not hitting ascx.vb page when attached to w3wp.exe process

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, vb.net-2010

I am currently trying to debug an ascx.vb page and the breakpoint is not hitting the page.
I am getting this error "The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document".

I have been using this project for 2 months and never encountered this error before.  I just did a small change on add button save it on chrome could see the change however, when i am debugging getting this issue for the first time.

**Steps done:**

Attach the breakpoint to the ascx.vb page
click on debug then attach to process as below (highlighted in yellow) :

[image]

[image]

**checks already done:**
Project is being run on debug mode

[image]

when debugging the symbols are not loaded.. have check Debug windows modules and is as below:

[image]

I have tried loading some symbols which created a folder symbolscache but still the debug point did not hit the page.

Is there something wrong in browser/iis or VS.
I was using VS 2017 but the same issue is occurring on VS 2019 professional.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Open `web.config` and confirm that debugging is enabled, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2019#configure-debugging-in-the-webconfig-file

Comment: Yes debug = "true" in web config

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable the "Just My Code" option in the Debug/General settings.

or

Right click the Solution in solution explorer, click "clean solution", this deletes all the compiled and temporary files associated with a solution. do a rebuild of the solution and try to debug again.